# Server is not sending the response in java using socket programming

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

When I'm sending some data to server from client, server is not giving me the response. When I enter all the data till Gender, the cursor blinks there. It seems it wants the user to insert more data. It is accepting data as much as I'm inserting. I have provided all my code below

My client side code is

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int age,carPrice,temp,temp1;
        String gender, s_temp;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1",1342);
        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
        PrintStream p = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        
        System.out.println("Enter Your Age: ");
        age = sc.nextInt();
        p.println(age);
        
        System.out.println("Enter the Cost of Vehicle: ");
        carPrice = sc.nextInt();
        p.println(carPrice);
        
        System.out.println("Enter Your Gender: ");
        gender = sc.next();
        p.println(gender);
        p.flush();
        
        temp = sc1.nextInt();
        System.out.println(temp);
        
        s_temp = sc1.next();
        System.out.println("The Gender is: " + s_temp);
        
        temp1 = sc1.nextInt();
        System.out.println(temp1);
      
        socket.close();
    }
}
```

My server side code:

```java
public class Server {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, SQLException{
        ServerSocket ssocket = null;
        Socket socket = null;
        System.out.println("Server Listening.......*");
        ssocket=new ServerSocket(1342);
        while(true){
            try{
                socket = ssocket.accept();
                System.out.println("Connection Established.");
                ServerThread st = new ServerThread(socket);
                st.start();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Connection Error....");
            }
        }
    } 
}

class ServerThread extends Thread{
    Socket s1 =null;   
    Scanner sc = null;
    PrintStream p=null;
  
    int age,carPrice,temp;
    String gender,temp1;
    
    public ServerThread(Socket s){
        s1=s;
    }
    
    public void run(){
        try{
            sc = new Scanner(s1.getInputStream());
            p = new PrintStream(s1.getOutputStream(),true);
           
            age = sc.nextInt();
            gender = sc.next();
            carPrice = sc.nextInt();
            
            p.println(age*2);
            p.println(carPrice);
            p.println("Your gender is: " +gender);
            
            s1.close();
            System.out.println("Connection Closed....");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        }
    }  
}
```

Tell me why my server is not sending a response. Correct it so that it can send respond to the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Age, car price and gender inputs, not read with send order. It must be read from the client in order.

Change below snippet. Also, add `sc.nextLine()` to skip newline after int read.

Server

```java
age = sc.nextInt();
carPrice = sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine();  // skip newline
gender = sc.next();
```

... instead of

```java
age = sc.nextInt();
gender = sc.next();
carPrice = sc.nextInt();
```

On the client-side, read order is not matched with send order. Also `sc.next()` reads one word, but you send many words while sending gender. So you have to change method with `sc.nextLine()`

Client

```java
temp = sc1.nextInt();
System.out.println(temp);

temp1 = sc1.nextInt();
System.out.println(temp1);

sc1.nextLine();  // skip newline

s_temp = sc1.nextLine();
System.out.println("The Gender is: " + s_temp);
```

.. instead of

```java
temp = sc1.nextInt();
System.out.println(temp);
        
s_temp = sc1.next();
System.out.println("The Gender is: " + s_temp);
        
temp1 = sc1.nextInt();
System.out.println(temp1);
```